# Loading sprites 1 time, or many times?

Tags: css, sprite

I'm wondering, if i'm doing this:

```
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background: transparent url(sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;">555</div>
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background: transparent url(sprite.png) -56px 0px no-repeat;">666</div>
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background: transparent url(sprite.png) -109px 0px no-repeat;">666</div>
```

Is this going to download the image 3 times ?

or is it going to download the image 1 time, and show different parts of it in the web page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be downloaded once unless cache is turned off, get Firebug and watch the HTTP requests then you'll get a better idea of what happens when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

It downloads the image 1 time only, and displays a portion of it in the different elements :)

It's explained in more detail at [A list Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)'s CSS sprites article.

Answer (score 3):

browsers *should* download it one time except you're setting some ugly kind of no-cache-header-things

Answer (score 1):

It'll only be downloaded once, don't worry.